# How to show a popup with textbox and browse button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In my asp page, i want to show a popup window whenever user clicks the button.The popup window contains one text box and submit button for getting the filepath from the user.

for example : i want a popup like this in stackoverflow site...

[image]

Please hele me to get this...

Comment: The "popup window" is just a div with an absolute position. Look at modal windows on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [EDITED:demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5vas/1/).Customize it to suit your needs.Let me know if need further help.
I have added a link which will display the popup on click.
After that the popup div is the actual popup , the popup div contains another div , just to hold the contents , in this case textbox and buttons.Here is the Html part.

```
<a id="popuplink" href="#">Click Me</a>
<div id="popup">
<div id="content">
<input type="text"/><input type="Button" value="Browse..."/>
    <input id="popupclose" type="Button" value="Close"/>   
 </div>   

</div>​
```

Here is CSS:

```
#popup
{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    width:250px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-155px;
    margin-top:-110px;
    border:5px solid red;
    background-color:#DEDFDE;
    padding:30px;
    z-index:102;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:10pt;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#content
{
    height:auto;
    width:250px;
    margin:60px auto;
}
#popupclose
{
    margin:35px 0 0 80px;
    width:50px;

}​
```

**EDIT:**
To get the value of the textbox check [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5vas/3/)

To call the javascript function on click of Asp.Net Button , try doing something like this.
Create a function which will show the popup.

```
function ShowPopUp()
{
  $('#popup').show("slow");
}
```

And on button click try this,

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", "ShowPopUp()", true);
```

**Additional Information** [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

Comment: Add the code here. If jsfiddle is down in an hour, your answer will be completely useless. Also, explaining what your code does is a nice thing.

Comment: @How to get the value from the text box when pressing close button?

Comment: @freebird : when i click browse button, the folder dialog box should open...how i do it?

Comment: @Saravanan which server side language are you using ?

Comment: @Saravanan to get the value of the textbox see the second link I posted.

Comment: @freebird : I am using asp.net(C#).How do i call this script from my asp page

Comment: @Saravanan that means you can use file upload control, so you want to call this script right , do you want to call this function from asp.net button's click event.

Comment: @freebird : i am not going to upload any file.But i need to get the path of the file from the folder dialog box.User can select the folder that contains the particular file... thats it

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to use `window.open`, here's some info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

Do you need something like this (this is a crude example as I don"t know the name of your page, etc, etc...):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win() {
window.open("mypage.html");
}
</script>
</head>    
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="open_win()">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

However I'd advise doing this in an unobtrusive manner.